# Populate a select based on other select

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I don't understand how to populate a 2nd select based on the choice I made on the 1st select.
What I want to do, is add a location. To add a location I have the first `select` that has 4 `options`: Continent, Country, Region an City.  And, if for example I `select` the city type, I want in my 2nd select to show only the Regions where i can connect the city. If I chose a Country, than I want the 2nd select to show me only the continents.

so far i have this:

```
<p><label for="type_id">Tip de locatie:</label><br />

<select class="styled" name="type_id" id="type_id">
    <option value="0">Alege...</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($place_type as $key => $type) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$type['id']?>"><?=$type['name']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</p>

<noscript>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Load Parents" />
</noscript>

<p><label for="parent_id">Leaga de:</label> <br />

<select class="styled" name="parent_id" id="parent_id">
    <option value="0">Alege...</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($places as $key => $place) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$place['id']?>"><?=$place['name']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</p>
```

I am using codeigniter framework, and i have this method in the controller:

```
public function get_place_parent()
{
    $this->load->model('places_model');
    $places = $this->places_model->get_places();
    $places = json_encode($places);
    return $places;
}
```

and the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  $("select#type_id").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("<?=site_url('admin/get_place_parent')?>",{type_id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + j[i] + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#parent_id").html(options);
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

I don't really understand how to do this. It is based on this tutorial: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `I don't really understand` is just to broad a statement.  Need to provide specific questions....what part don't you understand? WHat part of your code is or isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a snippet from one of my applications that does exactly what you're after.

companyNames is the id of the first dropdown, that is a list of the companies registered with us. When that changes it makes an ajax call to the admin/getAddresses function and sends the id from the companyNames dropdown. I included the controller function too, you can figure out the model as that won't be relevant to your application.

The controller then returns a json response with the data for the second dropdown which gets populated by the success function in the ajax cotnrol. First it removes any options already there (otherwise you keep appending every time you change the first dropdown) then it appends the new options from the json the controller returned.

**View**

```
$(document).on("change", "#companyNames", function() {
    $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>admin/getAddresses/",
        data: $row.find('input,select').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
        success: function(content) {
            if (content.status == "success") {
            $("#companyAddresses").find('option').remove();
            $.each(content.message, function(key, val) {
            $("#companyAddresses").append(
            '<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>'
            );
            });
            } else {                
                $("#error").html('<p>'+content.message+'</p>');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function getAddresses()
{
    $data = $this->input->getArray();
    $this->load->model('companies');
    $data['companyAddresses']=$this->companies->getCompanyAddresses($data['addCompany']);
    print json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "message"=>$data['companyAddresses']));
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time! I tried but doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong. How does it sends the id to the controller?

Comment: the line with the url is the address of the controller function. So you would put the controller function address in there just like if it were a normal function call. url: "<?=base_url()?>admin/getAddresses/", << replace that url with your controller function.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps

1) When you select a city type from a select box, you need a make an Ajax call in its onChange event.

2) Pass the selected city's id to the controller function.

3) Get the city's region from DB or wherever it is.

4) Then you can construct your options in controller function itself or you can pass it to Ajax function and construct your options in there also.

5) Add the constructed options in the regions select box.